# Susy: fluid layout up to the second breakpoint

Tags: susy-compass

If I understand correctly, Susy's `$container-style` variable is a global setting. This means that if you use the following code, both layouts will be fluid.

```
$total-columns: 4;
$total-columns-large: 8;
$container-style: fluid;

#page {
  @include container($total-columns, $total-columns-large);
}
```

But what if I want the 4-column layout to be fluid up to the (static) 8-column layout? I can think of a couple of ways to do that (like using `at-breakpoint` or `with-grid-settings`) but I'm curious if there is a better and/or recommended method.

Comment: That's more or less exactly what the default "magic" style is for. Do you need something different from that?

Comment: You're right, I tested some more and the magic style is almost exactly what I need. I was under the impression that you _must_ pass all breakpoints to the container mixin (ie. `container($total-columns, $total-columns-large)`) if you want span-columns to work properly... But I found out that you don't. That said, if I just use `container($total-columns-large)`, I do need to add the grid padding manually (in my specific case), but that's no big deal.