# Susy $container-style static -- changing to magic

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

**Question**

Is it possible to do the inverse of [Susy: fluid layout up to the second breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16276403/994466) -- or, in other words, have a Susy grid that is `static` up until a break and then `magic` beyond that point?

I admit, I'm not making a mobile-ready site. Instead, I want to use some of the fluid elements of the grid system for different monitor sizes and then 'turn off' this functionality when the browser window is too small.

By reading the documentation, I would think that I should set my global variable as such

```
$container-style: static;
```

And then at my specific `@at-breakpoint` do something like this

```
@at-breakpoint(XX) {
    @include set-container-width(yy, magic)
```

However, this has no (discernible) effect.

**Research Thus Far**

In the [set-container-width](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-set-container-width), I see that the $container-style argument

> <$style>: Optionally return static lengths for grid calculations. Default: $container-style.

Does this mean that you can only got *to* static (from 'magic' or 'fluid').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the container-related css output. The difference between a 'static' container and a 'magic' one is whether we use `width` or `max-width`. If you have already set the container width to be `30em` (for example), then adding a max-width of `50em` won't change anything. You have to also remove the previous width setting. You can do that either with more specific media-queries, or by simply adding `width: auto;` along with your new container-width setting.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the specific help and for the more general explanation of what gets generated and how.